# Dropped my Dell dual boot Vista /Ubuntu 12.04 Vista will not boot, only Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

I was looking to purchase a new computer  Lenovo  Essential G780 Laptop - 59381095 - Dark Brown: DOORBUSTER
http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/essential/g-series/g780/

I have started to do video editing with OneShot and love all the speed in Ubuntu it is where I try to do everything but I still do a lot of MS Access programming so I really need a dual boot.

There are no certified 17" models that I could find and when program the extra screen width is very helpful.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could assist me in determining if this G780 will be able to dual boot. I do not know much about hardware compatibility

Thank You Ubuntu Community   I suggest and promote Ubuntu whenever and where ever I can

Comment: Sorry shopping recommendations are off topic on AU.

Comment: Dual booting is not brand/model privative. All the [recently made] computers are dual boot capable if properly installed. I suggest you to check for the best specs and don't worry about dual boot. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

From dual boot Vista/Ubuntu experience be careful about how the dual installation is made. I would suggest making the second operating system installation as independent of the other operating system as possible. Make Ubuntu independent of Vista.